# VB.NET Custom SqlFactory, FileUpload Control issue

Tags: vb.net, file-upload

I've built the `SqlFactory` class to control my `StoredProcedures`, and I use it for all transactions between application and SQLServer. The part that I implemented last is file upload. But it won't do things as it should :( I've searched around the web not much could be found.

So basically I want to save my `Report` with `name`, `description`, and `image`.
`Name` and `description` are working perfectly, but for some reason it will not upload the file, it does not even reach the code for uploading it, which is:

```
If fuImage.PostedFile Is Nothing OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(fuImage.PostedFile.FileName) OrElse fuImage.PostedFile.InputStream Is Nothing Then
    'nothing to upload
Else
    Dim imagebytes(fuImage.PostedFile.InputStream.Length) As Byte
    fuImage.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(imagebytes, 0, imagebytes.Length)
    rep.FuImage = imagebytes
End If
rep.Name = txtName.Text
rep.Description = txtReportContent.Text
repFac.Save(rep)
```

The lines `rep.FuImage = imagebytes` and those below `if` statement are my factory lines it should be working but it's like `fuImage` `FileUpload` control never recognizes a file that's supposed to be selected.

This is my view part:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fuImage" runat="server" CssClass="fontChange" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rExpImage" runat="server" ControlToValidate="fuImage"
    ErrorMessage="Only .gif, .jpg, .png, .tiff and .jpeg"  ValidationExpression="(.*\.([Gg][Ii][Ff])|.*\.([Jj][Pp][Gg])|.*\.([Bb][Mm][Pp])|.*\.([pP][nN][gG])|.*\.([tT][iI][iI][fF])$)"
    ValidationGroup="ReportValidationSummary" CssClass="failureNotification">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Note: I am aware that FileUpload does not work in `asp:UpdatePanel`, hence I'm using regular `asp:Panel`, I beginning to doubt if there are issues with all `Panel` controls... Also, I've looked around problems that mention a lot of things, and I'm quite lost.

Please help, and thank you.

**EDIT:**
I've also tried working around `forms`, nothing came out of it. My server side `form` is placed on my `Master` page, and that's the only one i use. I've tried placing form on each page, instead. Nothing changed. (Read this in someones question, thought I'd try too.)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Problem was `<ContentTemplate>` was surrounding both `<asp:UpdatePanel>` and my `EditPanel` which was regular `<asp:Panel>`. That way it won't matter that `FileUpload` is not within update panel. It has to be set as a full post back with `<Triggers>`.

Code for `Triggers`:

```
<Triggers>
   <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Your_Control_ID" />
</Triggers>
```